# define help for variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, document

In Matlab, it is easy to generate "help" for a function, as follows.

```
function out = foo()
  % helpful information about foo
end
```

When we execute `help foo`, we get "helpful information about foo".

However, suppose we would like to define help for a variable, probably as a definition. How could we do such a thing? It would be nice if we could do something like

```
x = 3; % m ... position
help x
```

and get "m ... position". However, I don't believe such functionality exists.

The only reasonable way I see around this is to define every variable as a `struct` with keys `value` and `description`.

```
x.value = 3;
x.description = 'm/s ... position';
```

This requires we define every variable as a `struct`, which is kind of annoying and, I worry (should I?), unperformant (it's simulation code and these variables are accessed repeatedly).

Is there another solution I'm not considering? Should I be worried about making every variable a `struct`?

Comment: Another possibility is to have a single `struct` that includes a description of each variable name. So, for instance, `docs.x = 'm/s ... position'`. This solution is possibly preferable to the one I suggested above, since `x` wouldn't need to be a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be self-documenting. Instead of variable name `x`, use `position`.

Furthermore, all variables should be local, so you can easily look for its definition (with comment) within the function you are editing.

Variables declared further away (with larger scope within the function) should have longer, more self-explanatory names than variables with a smaller scope (e.g. use within a short loop.

There are only two three cases where variables are declared outside the function’s scope:

1. Class properties. [You can actually document these](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-help-for-classes.html#btleu9h-1).
2. In a script, you have access to variables that already existed before the script started. A good reason not to use scripts or depend on the base namespace in larger projects.
3. Global variables. You should never use global variables for many reasons. Just don’t.

Comment: How about documenting fields of a class property that's itself a structure? For instance, if a property `constants` had field `gradient`, could it be documented using the manner in which properties are documented? Your answer is comprehensive, but I'm looking to add more documentation for a simulation class that has constants and parameters that I'd like to document thoroughly and have exposed to the "user" without requiring they dig through the source.

Comment: Also, can you direct me to the documentation on class property documentation? I'm having trouble finding it and the ways I guessed didn't work.

Comment: It looks like a comment after the property declaration do generate documentation. So `property1 % property1 description` would work. It would be nice if this extended to `struct` field definitions in the same way, but it doesn't appear to do so.

Comment: @Rico: You can include larger blocks of documentation for each property, see the link I added to the answer. In this block you could document each of the fields of the property. If you really need to document each of these fields separately, you could create a custom class for this property instead. I don't think that would improve your documentation, though.